# Query row values as different Columns in Oracle 10g

Tags: sql, oracle10g

Hi Guys I have One table that Stores Student Scores for Different Subjects in the Field `stu_score`. The subjects are in the Field `ex_subjects`, I need to query the Table such that the Scores are arranged as separate Columns for each subject. I have Managed to Query for Mathematics like:

```
select stu_number, stu_name,  ex_name, stu_score as MATHEMATICS 
from EXAMS_MASTER_REGISTER 
where stu_level = '1' and stu_stream = 'EAST' 
and ex_semester = 'FIRST' 
and ex_name = 'MIDYEARS' 
and ex_subject = 'MATHEMATICS' 
and academic_year = '2012' 
order by stu_score desc
```

The Ouput is

[image: DB Screenshot]

I need the same for the Other Subjects in the table like `ENGLISH`, `PHYSICS`, `CHEMISTRY`.....
What is the best way to Approach this?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to add new columns to the result, with the scores for the other subjects? I mean do you want to see all the scores for all the subjects in one result set?

Comment: Yes in One result set...the example has only Mathematics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a query that only requires one access of the table, try:

```
select stu_number, 
       max(stu_name) stu_name, 
       ex_name, 
       max(case when ex_subject = 'MATHEMATICS' then stu_score end) as MATHEMATICS,
       max(case when ex_subject = 'ENGLISH' then stu_score end) as ENGLISH,
       max(case when ex_subject = 'PHYSICS' then stu_score end) as PHYSICS,
       max(case when ex_subject = 'CHEMISTRY' then stu_score end) as CHEMISTRY
from EXAMS_MASTER_REGISTER 
where stu_level = '1' and 
      stu_stream = 'EAST' and 
      ex_semester = 'FIRST' and 
      ex_name = 'MIDYEARS' and 
      academic_year = '2012' 
group by stu_number, ex_name
order by sum(stu_score) desc
```

Comment: Hey, I like this one better than mine!

Comment: Actually This is right...I think this is what I was Looking for....is there a way to have value zero for all the places where there is null?

Comment: @Stanley: the simplest way to have a 0 instead of null would be to include `else 0` before the `end` in the `case` expressions.

Comment: OK Mark Thanks I think I have what I wanted Thanks too ppeterka

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your query well, then this can be done so without changing your DB structure:

```
select MAIN.stu_number, MAIN.stu_name,  MAIN.ex_name, 
    MATHS.stu_score as MATHEMATICS, 
    ENGLISH.stu_score as ENGLISH, 
    PHYSICS.stu_score as PHYSICS, 
    CHEMISTRY.stu_score as CHEMISTRY
from EXAMS_MASTER_REGISTER MAIN
left join EXAMS_MASTER_REGISTER MATHS on MAIN.stu_number = MATHS.stu_number AND MATHS.ex_subject = 'MATHEMATICS'
left join EXAMS_MASTER_REGISTER ENGLISH on MAIN.stu_number = ENGLISH.stu_number AND ENGLISH.ex_subject = 'ENGLISH'
left join EXAMS_MASTER_REGISTER PHYSICS on MAIN.stu_number = PHYSICS.stu_number AND PHYSICS.ex_subject = 'PHYSICS'
left join EXAMS_MASTER_REGISTER CHEMISTRY on MAIN.stu_number = CHEMISTRY.stu_number AND CHEMISTRY.ex_subject = 'CHEMISTRY'
where MAIN.stu_level = '1' 
and MAIN.stu_stream = 'EAST' 
and MAIN.ex_semester = 'FIRST' 
and MAIN.ex_name = 'MIDYEARS' 
and MAIN.academic_year = '2012' 
order by (NVL(MATHS.stu_score,0) + NVL(ENGLISH.stu_score,0) + NVL(PHYSICS.stu_score,0) + NVL(CHEMISTRY.stu_score,0) ) desc
```

Note: I changed the order by, as in that form it was not usable anymore, this now sums the scores, and ranks by that.

However, this exact DB structure is bad. This is not in [First Normal Form (1NF)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form), which makes things unnecessarily difficult, and error prone. Also consider reading [2NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_normal_form), [3NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form), and [BCNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyce%E2%80%93Codd_normal_form) too (the other ones too, but AFAIK, these are the more widely known and used normal forms).  Ii assume you are learning, and this will get you on the right tracks.

You should separate your one table into (at least) two: one for the students' personal data (the columns now used with the MAIN alias), and one for the scores (the other columns).

Comment: Am not sure why but this Query does not return any Values.